# Inno Setup - UrlCreateFromPath

Tags: winapi, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'd like to be able to use the `UrlCreateFromPathW` function from Shlwapi.dll in my installer script, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```c
HRESULT UrlCreateFromPath(
  _In_    PCTSTR pszPath,
  _Out_   PTSTR  pszUrl,
  _Inout_ DWORD  *pcchUrl,
          DWORD  dwFlags
);
```

I've cobbled together the following from other "Inno Setup" tagged questions here, and from glancing at the JEDI translation for the DLL. `TryUrlCreateFromPath` always returns false. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```pascal
[Code]
const
  INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH = 2048 + 32 + 3;
  S_OK = $00000000;

function UrlCreateFromPathW(pszPath, pszUrl: string; var pcchUrl: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD): HResult; external 'UrlCreateFromPathW@Shlwapi.dll stdcall';

function TryUrlCreateFromPath(const path: string; var url: string): Boolean;
var
  charcount: dword;
  flags: dword;
begin
  SetLength(url, INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH);
  flags := 0;
  Result := UrlCreateFromPathW(path, url, charcount, flags) = S_OK;
  if Result then
    SetLength(url, charcount); 
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  URL: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  if TryUrlCreateFromPath('c:\temp', URL) then
    MsgBox('URL: ' + URL, mbConfirmation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox('ERROR', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pcchUrl` is an in/out argument. On input, it must contain a number of characters allocated in the `pszUrl`.

You do not initialize it. It most likely defaults to 0, hence the `UrlCreateFromPath` returns `E_INVALIDARG`.

Initialize it like:

```pascal
charcount := INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH;
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for pointing that out, that works perfectly. Much obliged to you for your help.